# update all widget instances vs updating current instance

Tags: android

I want to support multiple instances of a widget.  each instance is filled via a network call, so one will say "the age is 50", another will say "the age is 10".  I also want each widget updated in the period I specified in the provider xml(updatePeriodMillis).

When I add an additional instance to the home screen I dont want the others to be affected, so I only operate on the last element of the appWidgetIds array.  However, this prevents the periodic update from occurring on all instances.  Geneally speaking how can I get around this?